# How to let user enter python code and execute it?

Tags: python

The system is a web application using flask.
I have a class called ProcessingLayer that accepts a function as argument and executes that function.
I want the user to enter code in the form of a function and associate it with a string, then execute that function when the string is selected. The function must be able to accept parameters.

For example:

```
dict_of_functions = {}

def fun(*param):
   //do something

dict_of_functions[STRING_KEYWORD] = fun

layer = ProcessingLayer(dict_of_functions[STRING_KEYWORD])
```

Is there a library for processing something like this or how should I best execute it? Does each function and keyword the user create have to be on separate files and the main file (from which the functions are called) need to import those files? I tried searching, but found nothing about it. 
Thank you for every answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand exactly what you want to do. I think you probably want to execute python code which is stored inside a variable?

There is a [build-in function exec()](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#exec) you can use to execute code from an str().

For example your user entered code inside a form and you saved that in a variable:

```
my_form = "def fun():\n    pass\n\nfun()"  // This is the return from the Form
```

You can now execute the code with:

```
exec(my_form)
```

Python executes now:

```
def fun():
    pass

fun()
```

Be in mind, that the user can use that form to execue some really bad code.
It is a verry bad practice to execute user entered code.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough. I have an class called ProcesingLayer, which accepts a function (fun) as a parameter. Is there an alternative to the code you provided that allows passing parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest executing the code using restrictedpython:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/RestrictedPython

Here is an answer that provides some details:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/191623/best-practices-for-execution-of-untrusted-code